# SSD MobileNet v1 loss not converging bounding boxes all over the place

Tags: machine-learning, convergence, tensorflow, object-detection

I've trained SSD MobileNet v2 model using Tensorflow API on my own dataset of ~4k dog pictures and it displays bounding boxes all over the place. I've trained with batch size 1.
[image]

The same dataset trained on faster rcnn works really well, and detects dogs properly.
I've run 50k iterations, and total loss was spiking from 1.5 to 3 all the time in the end, with random bigger spikes, but overall it went down from 20

There wasn't a smooth and gradual decline, but a really spiky and uneven one with both models

Learning graph
[image]

I know it's a fast model with low precision, but it should at least more or less detect the object. How can I increase accuracy so it at least partially detects objects without showing completely false bounding boxes ?

Comment: Hi there. You've described the problem adequately, now please add a question. – *Reviewer*

Comment: So you've got code that executes. The next step is to experiment with regularization and parameter tuning.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adjusting the threshold in the code for inference. Default is 0.5, try out 0.7 or something like that.
I have been having the same issue and it works perfectly with the faster RCNN model. Here is an insight - https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/3196#issuecomment-359195620